# NDEF vs APDU NFC Android

Tags: android, nfc, apdu, ndef, contactless-smartcard

Can you tell me please what is the difference between NDEF (NFC Data Exchange Format) and APDU (Application Protocol Data Unit).

I have developed an Android application that reads NDEF messages, and I want to know if it can work for APDU data too.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### NFC Data Exchange Format (NDEF)

NDEF is a wrapper format that allows you to package a data payload together with meta information (such as a data type identification), and that permits combining multiple such packages (so-called "records") in one "message" that can be stored on NFC tags and transfered across an NFC link.

NDEF itself does not define **how** such data (messages) should be exchanged between NFC devices (i.e. it does not define the communication protocol and commands to read or store such data).

### Application Protocol Data Unit (APDU)

APDUs are the command and response packets for communication with smartcards. A command APDU consists of an instruction code and associated parameter data. A resonse APDU consists of response data and a response status code (in response to a preceding command APDU).

### What's the difference?

NDEF is data container for storing structured data on NFC tags and transfering such data over peer-to-peer links while APDUs are commands and responses of a communication protocol for smartcards.

### Are APDUs and NDEF somehow related?

With NFC Forum Type 4 tags, APDU commands (like READ BINARY and STORE BINARY) are used to read and store NDEF data into a file on that tag type. Other NFC Forum tag types do not rely on APDUs but use other command sets.

Comment: Than you for your response, but I stil have some confusion with apdu aids, how can i define them and why?